# Express/Node app issues with loading config file

Tags: node.js

In my file `app/controllers/activities.coffee` I am trying to load my config file like this:

```
cfg = require '../config/config'
```

But I keep getting this error:

`Error: Cannot find module '../config/config'`

Here is what that file looks like (`/config/config.coffee`):

```
path     = require 'path'
rootPath = path.normalize __dirname + '/..'
env      = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development'

config =
  development:
    root: rootPath
    app:
      name: 'app'
    port: 3000
    db: 'mongodb://localhost/app-development'

  test:
    root: rootPath
    app:
      name: 'app'
    port: 3000
    db: 'mongodb://localhost/app-test'

  production:
    root: rootPath
    app:
      name: 'app'
    port: 3000
    db: 'mongodb://localhost/app-production'


module.exports = config[env]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what if you try? **../../config/config**